# How to get selectedItem from a dropdown or listbox using IHTMLEventObj in C# Code

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webhooks, ihtmldocument

I want to log the selectedItem from a dropdown opened in a IE browser. Following is my code to get browser event on my c# program, Its working but I couldn't get the selected text of a listitem from the browser.

```
private void htmlDoc_KeyUp(IHTMLEventObj e)
        {
            var eventData = new EventDetail()
            {
                TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                TargetControl = new ControlDetail()
                {
                    Id = e.srcElement.id,
                    Name = e.srcElement.title,
                    ControlType = e.srcElement.tagName,
                    //LabelledBy = e.srcElement.outerHTML
                },
                Action = EventActions.KU,
                Data = Convert.ToChar(e.keyCode).ToString(),
                CursorLocation = new System.Windows.Point(e.screenX, e.screenY)
            };
            eventData.ToString().AppendToTextFile(logFilePath);
        }
```